# How do I extract data from a website for a data table using python?

Tags: python, interpretation

Im building tools for a business I am starting, and one of the tools I need is a live reader of scrap prices to put into my website as well as deciphering overhead/profit. How would I take that information and then put it into a live data table?

Very amateur programmer, but better to do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask and Beautiful Soup. With the flask you will be able to save the data after obtaining the information from the site after manipulating the html with beautiful soup.